# strange dependency of time to delete rows from table on number of rows

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a table that contains users that belong to one of the list, the table has about 23M rows now.

The structure of table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
 `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `list_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `subscriber_key` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email_address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `last_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '\nThe ip address of the subscriber that we can get when he opens the \nthe email or subscribe using subsribe form.\nTheoretically it can be used to segment by Location (which is not correct if someone uses proxy).',
 `preferred_format` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Preferred format of \n0 - HTML, \n1 -Text,\n2 - Mobile',
 `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4' COMMENT '1 - subscribed2 - unsubscribed3 - cleaned4 - not confirmed, it means the user subscribed but has not confirmed it yet.',
 `unsubscribe_reason` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `unsubscribe_reason_description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `cause_of_cleaning` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '\nThis field is the cause of moving the subscriber to the \n0 - not used\n1 - spam complaint\n2 - hard bounce\n3 - several soft bounces',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'The data when the subscriber was added. I suppose this field can be used in the conditions forming the segment',
 `last_changed` datetime NOT NULL,
 `unsubscribe_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`subscriber_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email_list_id` (`email_address`,`list_id`),
 KEY `FK_list_id` (`list_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) REFERENCES `lists` (`list_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42236572 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='\nEmails and other contact info about\nthe people'
```

Sometimes there can be data in child table to contacts with additional fields, but in this case (for list_id = 81) there are not such data.

For request

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM contancts
WHERE list_id =81
```

it shows:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  subscribers     ref     FK_list_id  FK_list_id  4   const   1
```

When I tried to delete rows that meet condition:

```
DELETE
FROM contancts
WHERE list_id=81
```

Tha table has some 3 indexes now:
subscribers     0   PRIMARY     1   subscriber_id   A   23196385    NULL    NULL        BTREE
subscribers     0   email_list_id   1   email_address   A   23196385    NULL    NULL        BTREE
subscribers     0   email_list_id   2   list_id     A   23196385    NULL    NULL        BTREE
subscribers     1   FK_list_id  1   list_id     A   17  NULL    NULL        BTREE

I see strange dependency of time it takes to delete on the number of rows that meet the condition:

```
2K rows - 0.0847 sec, 5K – 0.2856 , 10K – 21.3428 , 20K – 34.41, 50K – 61.2596, 
100K - 99.7257.
```

I don't clear now list online, but queue this operation, and delete them by 1000 subscribers in background.

But I wonder why time increases so much from 5K to 10K rows. Could somebody explain why it happens?

Comment: What is the exact query you're running to remove 10k rows?  If the rows all actually have the value 81 for list_id, that could be affecting indexes.

Comment: Query is DELETE FROM contancts WHERE list_id=81. Number of rows is the number of rows that meet this condition list_id = 81 in this case. So if we have 10K rows that meet this condition, time increases significantly. The table has about 23M rows now.

Comment: Can you `SHOW CREATE TABLE contancts`?

Comment: I added structure of table to my post.